# How to persist an entity in Spring Data JPA without getting associated objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have 2 entities

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        private User() {

        }

    ... other fields omitted ...

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
        private List<Car> cars;

    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car implements Serializable {

    public Car() {

    }

... Other fields omitted ...

    @Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

}
```

Now, whenever I call save on my CarRepository, It requires me to have a User object on the user field. That way, I still have to call the findById method in my UserRepository like

```
...
car.setUser(userRepository.findById(userId));
carRepository.save(car);
...
```

Is there a way for Spring Data JPA to just save using userId, where I don't have to get a user object before persisting the car object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating `User` object and setting the `userId` there and set it inside `car` object.

```
User existingUser = new User();
existingUser.setId(userId);
car.setUser(existingUser);
carRepository.save(car);
```